# Docker compose cannot access to localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am currently using `docker-compose` with Ruby on Rails and having a serious problem. I can't access to localhost by typing `localhost:3000` on chrome search bar. Here's the `docker-compose.yml`.

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  rails:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/rails/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      RAILS_ENV: development
    restart: always
    command: bundle exec rails s -b '0.0.0.0'
  nginx:
    build: ./docker/nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on:
      - rails
```

and here is the output of `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
abb871c7091e        _ex_nginx              "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:3000->80/tcp   mates_ex_nginx_1
7507ee9496c4        _ex_rails              "./docker-rails-entr…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute                          mates_ex_rails_1
```

And result of the `cat /etc/hosts` is as follows.

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost

127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost

# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

And on the docker log, it says rails is running on `0.0.0.0:3000`.

```
rails_1  | * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
```

Any answer will be appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give an example of a request that’s failing?  Where are you making the request from?  Remember that each container is its own `localhost` and is different from the host’s `localhost`.

Comment: @DavidMaze Sorry I didn't make it clear. I just typed in localhost:3000 on the chrome search bar and it refuses to connect.

Comment: What is your host environment?  (Are you using Docker Toolbox on a Windows system?) Does your nginx config listen on port 80?

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm using Docker for Mac. Yes, on the `default.conf` file, I wrote `listen 80 default_server; listen [::]:80 default_server;`